# Scrapy: running multiple nested searches against same URL

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm pretty new to Python and very new to Scrapy.  I'm trying to build a spider that will go to a given URL and run multiple nested searches within that site.  For example, if I were searching an online store, I'd start off with a request to http://www.mystore.com, then search through 3 levels of submenus within the site for various products which are specified at runtime via a CSV input file.  At each level in the submennus, I am looking for the target category and firing off a request to get that sub-category, until I get to level 3 when I parse the results looking for a particular item.

- Store base URL --> Home --> Kitchen --> Appliances:  Parse results
  looking for "blender".
- Store base URL --> Home --> Kitchen --> Appliances:  Parse results
  looking for "kettle".
- Store base URL --> Home --> Electrical --> Video:  Parse results
  looking for "dvd player".
- Store base URL --> Home --> Garden --> Tools:  Parse results looking
  for "strimmer".
- Store base URL --> Clothing --> Men --> Trousers:  Parse results
  looking for "denim".

I can load the search data into my CrawlSpider and tell Scrapy to run all these searches, but Scrapy sees that the starting URL is the same, so it only runs the first request and regards all the others as duplicates.

The site I'm crawling doesn't have a RESTful interface, so I can't specify request URLs to go straight to the relevant sub-category.  Instead I have to look through the navigation links at each level to find the next sub-category I want to crawl.

I don't want to have to pass the entire tree of searches around within the spider and keep checking where I am in the tree. The searches work fine for a single search e.g. for the "blender" above, but  I can't figure out how to persuade Scrapy to run all the searches separately.

Can anybody point me towards some examples or other documentation for doing this kind of thing?

Comment: Could you post your existing spider code and the CSV file so we can take a look at it please? :)

Comment: Sorry, but my employer is a bit paranoid about posting code online, so I can't put it on here.

Answer (score 1):

to tell [linkextractor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) not to filter same urls use:

> unique (boolean) – is a boolean that specifies if a duplicate filtering should be applied to links extracted.

however, from your question it seem that every site you want to crawl need a separate spider, while all share the same pipelines etc. (classic scrapy project structure), you should also consider using simple Spider and not CrawlSpider, note that there is no need to remember "the entire tree of searches", simple fire as many requests as needed and let scrapy queue them and call their callback one by one.

Comment: Thanks Guy.  But how do I tell Scrapy not to filter the same URLs?  I'm simply sub-classing CrawlSpider here, and I'm not creating my own link extractors.  Also, I don't think I can run separate spiders, as I don't know what categories I will be searching for until runtime.  I call Scrapy as "scrapy crawl myspider" and it reads the search parameters from a CSV file, so how would I name the spiders dynamically?  Sorry for all the stupid questions, but this is all very new to me!

Comment: I understand you have a list of websites to crawl that will end up translating to a unify data structure, so you are basically taking an unstructured data (html pages in various websites) and transform it to structure data (i.e. database table, json, etc) correct ?

Answer (score 0):

@Guy:

The search params come from rows in a CSV file, but logically they would be something like this:

- www.mystore.com --> find "Home" --> find "Kitchen" --> find "Appliances" --> parse to find "blender" items.
- www.mystore.com --> find "Home" --> find "Kitchen" --> find "Appliances" --> parse to find "kettle" items.
- www.mystore.com --> find "Home" --> find "Electrical" --> find "Video" --> parse to find "dvd player" items.
- www.mystore.com --> find "Home" --> find "Garden" --> find "Tools" --> parse to find "strimmer" items.
- www.mystore.com --> find "Clothing" --> find "Men" --> find "Trousers" --> parse to find "denim" items.
- www.anotherstore.com --> find "Home" --> find "Kitchen" --> find "Appliances" --> parse to find "blender" items.
- ...etc

So the search is logically a set of nested queries, but I would rather run separate searches for each line above, if I can persuade Scrapy to ignore the fact that there are several searches that start from www.mystore.com.  The data gets stored as a set of simple CSV records i.e. one for each item extracted. So there is no real need to build a tree, except that I don't know how to run multiple different searches against the same base URL via Scrapy.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it working.

- Start request is base URL e.g. www.mystore.com
- Parse response from start request then simply run all the searches
  based on the top-level navigation links extracted from the base page.

It's not efficient, and I'll need to re-work it if the data volumes go up, but right now it seems to work.

Thanks for your advice.